# How to disable required field validation for LastName in paypal form?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-sandbox

I have an eCommerce site which will only ask for a single Name field from user, (First Name). and I saw that the Last Name and First Name are optional in the PayPal documentation. When the PayPal form loads its showing the last name field and when ever I click "Pay", It shows the Last Name required error message as shown in the message https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C35534687298D6CE!2911&authkey=!AG-Hz6sCZ0xaSwQ&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng.

How to disable required field validation for LastName in paypal form?

Thanks
Abdussalam